# django: how to recursively get the modified date from a model and its related models and their related models

Tags: django

I have the following models:

I have Four Main models which dont have any forieng key fields:

```
class Main1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Main2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Main3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Main4(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I have the following models which depend on Foriengn fields:

```
Class Related1(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main4 = models.ForeignKey(Main4,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)



Class Related2(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main3 = models.ForeignKey(Main3,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related1 = models.ForeignKey(Related1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


Class Related3(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main2 = models.ForeignKey(Main2,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related2 = models.ForeignKey(Related2,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


Class Related4(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main1 = models.ForeignKey(Main1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related3 = models.ForeignKey(Related3,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Here `Main1` is related to `Related4` Model, but `Related4` has also another foriegn key `Related3` which further depends on others

I am trying to find out the modified date of all the Models related to Main1 for a given slug field.

I want to save the latest updated datetime for all the related objects recursively and later store that in my database. I am doing some complex calculation. I dont want to do it if no data has changed. For that i want to compare the latest updated datatime with the one that i store in the database.

```
Getting the modified date (i.e updated field) of Main1 instance

main1_instance = get_object_or_404(Main1, slug=slug)

main1_instance_modified_date = main1_instance.updated

Getting the latest modified date (i.e updated field) of Main1_Related4 objects

main1_related4_objects =  main1_instance.related4_set.all()

main1_related4_objects_latest_change = main1_related4_objects.latest('updated')
```

But Related4 has foriengn key Related3 and Related3 is depend on Main2 and Related2 and so on

I want to get all the modified dates (i.e updated field) for all the connected objects for Main1 instance. Is there any short way.

Comment: Try using the `Greatest` database function? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest

Comment: `main1_instance.related4_set.annotate(last_updated=Greatest('updated', 'main1__updated','related3__updated','related3__main2__updated'))`. Will radding related3__main2 work in my case